# Docker compose new image and instance

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running docker machine server where I run docker instances. I would like to run multiple servers(instances) from same docker-compose file in different folder.

I have configurated two Dockerfile. One is mysql and other one is for nodejs. 
Here is the example:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install -g pm2
ADD package.json package.json
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 3000
```

Now I run those from docker-compose like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    service:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-server
        container_name: server
        ports:
        - "2000:3000"
        restart: always
        working_dir: /home/app
        volumes:
        - ./:/home/app
        command: sh -c 'nodemon'
    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
        - ../mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

When I add new environment-folder(folder with these files and some updated nodejs stuffs) and try to run docker-compose. It's stops already running dockers with same setups and recreates that.

How I can run multiple instances from same docker-compose file?

Comment: Can you add some information like the exact commands you are running and the folders / structure where they're being run?

Answer (score 1):

As is: you can't because you have only one 3306 port on you host machine. But if you let docker compose manage the links you can use `docker-compose scale SERVICE=N` where SERVICE is your service name, and N the number of copy. For example whit this comnfiguration :

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  client:
    image: explorer-client
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - client-server
      - client-watcher
  server:
    image: explorer-server
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - client-server
      - server

networks:
  client-server:
    driver: bridge
  server:
    driver: bridge
```

you can scale the server service by doing `docker-compose scale server=2` because it's not explicitely linked to the client by a port.

Comment: You are right, but you forgot mention of removing `container-name` line from `docker-compose` file. But this is seat of the trouble.